# How can I align on colons in scalariform?

Tags: scalariform

I have a case class like this:

```
case class Foo(
  one: String,
  another: Int,
  stuff: Boolean
)
```

Is there a setting in scalariform to get this? (aligned on the colon)

```
case class Foo(
  one    : String,
  another: Int,
  stuff  : Boolean
)
```

I'm using sbt-scalariform with a setting setPreference(AlignParameters, true)

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported. There are [a number of feature requests](https://github.com/scala-ide/scalariform/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+align) related to enhanced alignment of parameters to class and method definitions.